# Use Laravel Language key inside another key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Language file

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CUSTOM Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
|  
|
*/

'title_equipment' => 'Equipment',
'title_equipment_new' => 'Add new '.('custom.title_equipment'), 

];
```

Above is the new language file which I've created with laravel 5.4. I want to use the `title_equipment` variable inside the `title_equipment_new` variable. 
I tried the above way and tested the output in a blade template but it returns the key of the variable which means it's not available to use.

My view

```
<h1 class="page-header">
    <small>{{ __('custom.title_equipment_new') }} </small>
</h1>
```

Please note that `custom` is the file name of the new language file.

Comment: Have you tried `'title_equipment_new' => 'Add new '.__('custom.title_equipment')`

Comment: @linktoahref Yes I tried that way but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, especially when you outsource translation files to companies that will translate them for you, it's best to interpolate these items using `sprintf`. This means the string to translate has the whole context as languages have completely different ways of structuring sentences.

I would recommend this translation file

```
'title_equipment' => 'Equipment',
'title_equipment_new' => 'Add new %s.',
```

Then in your blade template

```
sprintf(__('custom.title_equipment_new'), __('custom.title_equipment'));
```

An actually translated example might be

```
'buy_car' => 'Buy %s car', // %s refers to colour
'car_colour_red' => 'Red',
```

The french translation file might be (I used Google translate)

```
'buy_car' => 'Acheter une voiture %s',
'car_colour_red' => 'rouge',
```

But your blade template would still be:

```
sprintf(__('custom.buy_car'), __('custom.car_colour_'.$colour));
```

You wouldn't be able to something like this

```
__('Buy').' '.__($colour).' '.__('car');
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the key of the variable instead of any text, because you didn't call the function like `__()` or `trans()` to translate the text. You only have surround your text by brackets which doesn't affect the text.

If you use the function `__()` or `trans()` it normally translate an existing key, but inside an language file you will probably get an Exception in `\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php`, so it's ain't possible.

Comment: please check my question again. I've added my code from the view. I've called the function as the standard way. using "__()"

Comment: @HashanKanchana Yes you call it the standard way inside the blade view, but not inside the lang file and this wouldn't work anyway. So Scopey has a good workaround.

Comment: I tried to use that way inside the language file also but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get more up-to-date, with newer versions of Laravel it is possible to define placehoders in your language strings:

```
'title_equipment' => 'Equipment',
'title_equipment_new' => 'Add new :equipment.',
```

The usage would be:

```
__('title_equipment_new', [ 'equipment' => __('title_equipment') ])
```

with that you can also interpolate different words/phrases to different places inside the string.

For detailed information, heres the documentation: [Laravel docs on localization](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Use  `__()` helper function  instead of `trans()`.